# LAN suddenly won't connect for no reason

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My sister and I have been playing Minecraft LAN together easily for the last six months. And then suddenly a week ago, it just stopped working. Anytime we try to connect, we get the message: "Connection timed out; no further information."

We don't know what has happened. It was working fine, until it wasn't. I've looked at over 20 different forums and help sites, and I've even tried just trying out my own solutions. Nothing has worked. We're on the same network, in the same room, different player names, Java can get through our firewall, we're on the same version, we're both playing vanilla Minecraft, and we don't know what's gone wrong. All of the forums I've looked at have all just been stuff like "Me too!" or "Have you solved it yet?" or "Woopsie! It couldn't get through our firewall! Thanks!"... Nothing useful to our situation.

Comment: Are you using Wifi, or an actual LAN cable? Have you tried restarting the Modem? Possibly a `ipconfig /release` and `/renew`? Tell us what you *have* already tried in your answer, so we don't have to guess at what *might* be the issue, and we can pinpoint exactly what is going wrong for you.

Comment: I'm using Wifi. We had some electrical work done, and we had to unplug the modem for a bit, so does that count as restarting it?...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated, but should work. Make sure this is from the person trying to connect to LAN's computer.

First, find your IPv4. If the computer is Windows, press start and search cmd. Open it, type in "ipconfig" and press Enter. If the computer is Mac, [follow this guide.](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6526)

If use Windows, look for the part that says IPv4 address. After the dots and colon, you will find it. Copy that address.

When you open to LAN, it will say it was hosted on a port, we'll use 01659 as an example.

Get the person connecting to go to Multiplayer, then press Direct Connect. Paste in the IPv4, then add a colon (:). Type in the port, and you're good to go!

It should look something like: 12.34.0.56:78901

Please note that the port changes each time, so you can't use Add Server.

Hope that helped! :)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't help. Direct connect is already what we do. For some reason, LAN servers won't show up in multiplayer screen, so that's what we have to do... :P